# Running MSBuild script from TeamCity fails

Tags: tfs, msbuild, teamcity

I'm migrating my team's CI from TFS to TeamCity.

As part of my build I need to update a few files and check the changes back to TFS.
I've created a simple MSBuild script that checkout the files, update them and check the changes back in.

The script works great on my machine but when I run it fro TeamCity I get the following error:
*TF30063: You are not authorized to access ...*

Is there a way I can run only the MSBuild step and another user? 
Is there a way to grant TeamCity's Agent the needed permissions to connect to TFS

Comment: What are you checking in and out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you add the Team City Agent account to the team project security groups in Team Foundation Server?

Comment: Not yet - probably what I'll do